# PHP - User defined function returns a fatal error

Tags: php

So I have this user defined function:

```
        function ackermann($n, $m)
        {
            if ($n == 0)
            {
                return 1 + $m;
            }

            if ($m == 0)
            {
                return ackermann($n - 1, 1);
            }

            return ackermann($n - 1, ackermann($n, $m - 1));
        }

        echo ackermann(3, 3);
```

This should return the value of 61, but it returns this fatal error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 262144 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php on
>   line 316

This is only a part of a set of programs that we are tasked to code in PHP since I am taking an introductory subject to PHP. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? So much recursion...

Comment: this function is show result 61 , not error  https://3v4l.org/MmGcK

Comment: This code works fine at my end may be there something else cause this error can you please share full code

Comment: @Paradigm : Have you placed this code in a seperate file an run it. Seems some error occuring due to some other reason

Comment: Check line 316 on PhpProject1\index.php.

Comment: if line 316 contains above function code then you are going into an infinite loop try to debug it with simpply printing value at every call look how it it is executing

Comment: This is a recursive function. I tried a running it in a seperate file and it worked. Though no idea why it won't work with the other codes. The error just points out to that part whenever I try to put it there.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the PHP is unable to complete the request within the memory assigned to it.

Solution is to increase `memory_limit` in `php.ini`. 
It should be `128M` by default, change it to 512 or 1024;

```
memory_limit = 512M;
```

If it still gets exhausted, try to analyse your code and check if it's not executing in loop.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of this:

```
return ackermann($n - 1, ackermann($n, $m - 1));
```

You are trying to call ackermann function in ackermann function, which tries to call ackerman function, which calls ackerman function...

It won't ever work then.

What do you want to achieve?